# Bug with \llbracket

Tags: bugs, stmaryrd

I've encountered the following bug.

The piece of code `Soit $p\in \left \llbracket {0}, {m^2} \right \rrbracket$`
produces the output

[image]

I've tried to produce a MWE but, so far, I've not been able to. The following MWE fails to reproduce the same output (I mean, the following MWE produces the output I am waiting for).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\integerBrackets}{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}
\newcommand{\integerInterval}[2]{\integerBrackets*{#1, #2}}

\begin{document}
Soit $p\in \integerInterval{0}{m^2}$
$\integerInterval{0}{m^2}$
\end{document}
```

This means that the bug may be caused by an interaction with other packages.

So, my question is: without any MWE... does anyone have a clue about what could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: somewhere you have defined llbracket to be essentially `[[` or perhaps `[\![` so it looks Ok at normalsize but `\left` only sees the first `[` just stick `\typeout{\meaning\llbracket}` after every package in your preamble and see where it changes

Comment: This can only happen if `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` contains multiple characters (like `[[` and `]]`) rather than a single glyph, so `\left` and `\right` only applies to the first in the set.

Comment: You could try extending the working MWE into your real document, so start with this code, and then add content from your original document piece by piece until the problem appears or until you have fully reconstructed your document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere you have defined the commands as fake double brackets rather than a single glyph, so `\left` and `\right` are only seeing half of the pair.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\def\llbracket{[\![}
\def\rrbracket{]\!]}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\integerBrackets}{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}
\newcommand{\integerInterval}[2]{\integerBrackets*{#1, #2}}

\begin{document}
Soit $p\in \integerInterval{0}{m^2}$
$\integerInterval{0}{m^2}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You perfectly nailed it!